# How do I delete the disabled="disabled" attribute from my website code if it keeps coming back?

Tags: html

I am working on an application form webpage for a business website. And no matter how many times I delete it, change it, use the exhausted `.removeAtt`, `disabled="disabled"` attribute attached to my submission button WILL JUST NOT GO AWAY. After deleting the `disabled="disabled"` attribute, I opened the page in both notepad and Dreamweaver and it's gone like it's supposed to be.

But when I open the page in a browser, the Submit button stays dead and when I look into the code from the browser that `disabled="disabled"` attribute still there. I normally loath going onto forums like this, but I've been at this for days now and I'm just at my wits end with zero progress. Please help me because I really need to get this webpage done and if I can't get the submit button to at least respond, then all the work I put in this will go down the drain and I can't just start over from scratch.

Here's a block of code for the `submit` button I'm having trouble with:

```
<div class="form-element-wrapper" id="Submit-id">
  <div style="text-align: left;">
    <input type="submit" class="form-element" name="Submit" value="Submit" disabled="disabled">
  </div>
</div>
</form>
</td>
<td align="left" valign="top" width="45%">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Please help. :(

Comment: You probably have Javascript code that is setting it.

Comment: This is not enough code for us to help you. Please post the code in a gist so we can see what else is on that page (javascript) that might be generating it. Or, of the backend is PHP, we need to see that too. Etcetera.

Comment: At the very least, the example code in your question is very much invalid. Is there a back-end system of some sort that generates this code?

Comment: I'm afraid the answer field isn't letting me type enough characters to post the full code. Here's the javascript part at the top of the code. I'll try to figure out how to post the rest of the full code. Thanks guys. I really appreciate your replies. :)

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
  var builderSettings = {
    appRoot: '//app.neo.registeredsite.com/neo/',
    appRelativePath: '/neo',
    assetsRoot: '//assets.neo.registeredsite.com',
    repositoryRoot: '//repository.neo.registeredsite.com',
    spRoot: '//repository.neo.registeredsite.com/starting-points',
    usersRoot: '//users.neo.registeredsite.com',
    sitesearchUrl: '//sitesearch.services.matrixbuilder.com/sitesearch/search',
    siteDomain: 'nsldp.org',
    isBuilder : false,
    isPreview : true
 
  };
</script>

Comment: Your html is bizarre. Table elements all mixed up with form elements and nothing properly nested. You may have bigger problems than your disabled submit button. But one thing is for sure, that disabled attribute is being set either server-side by some code that generates the page or by javascript. What is this site based on - some kind of platform like WordPress, or have you written it all yourself?

Comment: PS - post your code by editing the original question, not in a comment.

Comment: Ah, there's a little story to that. I used to host my business website on web.com, but for reasons of my own I had it transferred to a different host. Before the transfer, I saved the whole website to my computer before uploading it to the new host. Everything worked except for the application form webpage. This is because the application webpage was created after the transfer completed so I could only save it from a preview in the web.com builder instead of saving it directly from the site like I normally would. Building an application form from scratch is for geniuses like you guys. :)

Comment: Of course, my apologies. I'm afraid I'm still new to this site...Still new to a lot of things really.

Comment: 1) Check via FTP that the new file is actually uploaded, 2) Flush your browser cache to make sure the browser has not cached an old version of your page. 3) Add a comment or something to the page so you can see  if that change takes place.

Comment: I didn't think web.com allows FTP. I could never find any ftp settings for it.

Comment: If it did allow FTP, I would have solved this a long time ago by just connecting to my web.com directory via FTP and directly downing the application .html file to my computer without all this hassle. I also tried posting the full code to my original question like Sharper and others have suggested but it's not letting me.